# how do i download doc from google insight in java

Tags: java, python

i was able to get this code for c# which works perfectly fine..but due to dependancy issues i need the java/ python equivalent of it..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        String userName = "*******";
        String password = "*******";
        var response =        client.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email="+userName+"@gmail.com&Passwd="+password+"&service=trendspro&source=test-test-v1");
        var sid = response.Split('\n')[0];
        client.Headers.Add("Cookie", sid);
        String downloadURL = "http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?cat=0-7&geo=BR&date=today%207-d&cmpt=geo&content=1&export=1";
        byte[] csv = client.DownloadData(downloadURL);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(csv));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a work dump. Please change that by telling us what you have you tried, and what problems are you having with your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fetching a file

The [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) module is what you're looking for here.  A [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html) is available as well.  For authentication, you're looking for `HTTPBasicAuthHandler`. See http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples for an example.

### Handling CSV data

For handling CSV data, you'll want to use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

### Question is lacking effort

If the documentation provided here is not enough for you to fake your way through a solution, please update the question with the things you've tried and specific questions on what isn't working for you.